# Can i use one domain for two website? About GCP and Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, dns, firebase-hosting, keystonejs

I would like to use firebase hosting to host the frontend React web, and my "keystone" backend hosting on GCP VM instance, can i use the same domain for those two websites? Thank you~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

same domain with different routes can be used eg domainname.com/site1,domainname.com/site2